# Ошибка в реализации метода "backpropagation"

Tags: c++, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение

Доброе времени суток!

Правильно ли я написан метод "backpropagation"? Мне некорректно считает считает веса для нейронов.

Переменные:

```
int inputs[3];//входные нейроны
double hidN[2];//нейроны скрытого слоя
double output;//выходной нейрон


double weight_1[3][2], weight_1_2[3][2];// веса для скрытого слоя
double weight_2[2], weight_2_2[2];//веса для выходного нейрона

double actual_predict;// актуальное предсказание 

double learning_rate;// равен 0.08


double error_layer_2, gradient_layer_2, weights_delta_layer_2;
double error_layer_1[2], gradient_layer_1[2], weights_delta_layer_1[2];
```

Реализация:

```
void train(double expected_predict)
    {
        // делает предсказание 
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            hidN[i] = sigmoid((inputs[0] * weight_1[0][i]) + (inputs[1] * weight_1[1][i]) + (inputs[2] * weight_1[2][i]));
        output = sigmoid((hidN[0] * weight_2[0]) + (hidN[1] * weight_2[1]));
        actual_predict = output;

        //корректирует веса для весов скрытого слоя(hidN)
        error_layer_2 = actual_predict - expected_predict;
        gradient_layer_2 = actual_predict*(1 - actual_predict);
        weights_delta_layer_2 = error_layer_2 * gradient_layer_2;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)// скорее всего здесь ошибка(
            weight_2[i] = weight_2[i] - hidN[i] * weights_delta_layer_2 * learning_rate;

        // корректирует веса для входных нейронов (inputs)
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            error_layer_1[i] = weights_delta_layer_2 * weight_2[i];
            gradient_layer_1[i] = hidN[i] * (1 - hidN[i]);
            weights_delta_layer_1[i] = error_layer_1[i] * gradient_layer_1[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)//или здесь 
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                weight_1[i][j] = weight_1_2[i][j] - inputs[i] * weights_delta_layer_1[j] * learning_rate;


    }
```

Источник алгоритма:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HA-F6cZPvrg

Comment: Вы хотя бы указали размерность и тип weight_1, inputs, weight_1_2, error_layer_1, hidN. И из какого источника брали сам алгоритм.

Comment: А почему вы не применяете sigmoid функцию для выходного слоя? И какая структура вашей нейросети?

Comment: ошибка, я уже тупо перебираю комбинации(

Comment: Странностей в коде хватает. Ошибок навскидку не видно...

Comment: @AnT например ?

Comment: @Роман Худобердин: В "полном" коде (по ссылке) элемент массива `weight_2_2[i]` выступает лишь в роли промежуточной переменной в цикле вычисления элемента массива `weight_2[i]`. То есть вообще не видно зачем понадобился именно *массив* `weight_2_2[]` , да еще и "долгоживущий" (то есть член класса). На первый взгляд никакого массива не нужно: хватило бы обычной локальной переменной внутри цикла. Разумеется, это основано на предполождении, что код по сылке полон.

Comment: @AnT возможно я просто забыл его удалить в ходе своих экспериментов

Comment: @Роман Худобердин: В любом случае, это не ошибка.

Comment: @AnT ну да, где же она может таится ?в примере где высчитываются новые веса после "weight_2[i]" и "weight_1[i][j]" идет операция вычитания и присваивания, но если ех использовать получается какой-то бред(((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код с ошибкой:

```
weight_1[i][j] = weight_1_2[i][j] - inputs[i] * weights_delta_layer_1[j] * learning_rate;
```

Код без ошибки:

```
weight_1[i][j] = weight_1[i][j] - inputs[i] * weights_delta_layer_1[j] * learning_rate;
```